# How to pattern match on list vs single element

Tags: erlang, pattern-matching

I am trying to understand how can you pattern match in Erlang for single elements vs lists:

```
guarded(T) when T>5 ; T<3 -> 3+T;
guarded([X,Y]) when X>3,Y>3 ->{X+1,Y+1};
guarded([X,_|[T,_]]) when X rem 2==0, T rem 2 =/= 1-> [T,X];
guarded(_)->"something else".



guarded([1,2,3]).  -> goes into case 1 , how can i make sure it doesn't (and goes to last case)
```

> ** exception error: an error occurred when evaluating an arithmetic expression
>        in function  main:guarded/1

Where would i need to place the first case , when i want to pattern match on single elements.I mean i want to have a case that works for single elements and a wild-card-pattern too (last expression).

Comment: In addition to the answers already given, it is interesting to note that in erlang the types are ordered, so a comparison between two variables of any types is always valid and will return true or false. For example any list is bigger than any number. This is the reason why your first statement will always match, except when T is a number between 3 and 5.

Comment: That was already described in an answer 4 hours before you posted your comment, so once again it looks like you are plagiarizing people's answers.

Comment: Its okay , for me it was valuable information  finding out lists can be compared with numbers and are taken as  greater than numbers by default.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add an [`is_list/1`](http://erlang.org/doc/man/erlang.html#is_list-1) check to your guards to check that `T` is not a list:

```
guarded(T) when not is_list(T) andalso (T>5 orelse T<3) -> 3+T;
guarded([X,Y]) when X>3, Y>3 ->{X+1,Y+1};
guarded([X,_|[T,_]]) when X rem 2==0, T rem 2 =/= 1-> [T,X];
guarded(_)->"something else".
```

Or you could use [`is_number/1`](http://erlang.org/doc/man/erlang.html#is_number-1) or [`is_integer/1`](http://erlang.org/doc/man/erlang.html#is_integer-1) to check that `T` is a number or an integer respectively:

```
guarded(T) when is_number(T) andalso (T>5 orelse T<3) -> 3+T;
guarded([X,Y]) when X>3, Y>3 ->{X+1,Y+1};
guarded([X,_|[T,_]]) when X rem 2==0, T rem 2 =/= 1-> [T,X];
guarded(_)->"something else".
```

Comment: I don't think priority is right there; it means `(not is_list(T) andalso T>5) orelse T<3` instead of desired  `not is_list(T) andalso (T>5 orelse T<3)`.

Comment: I'd still use `,` instead of `andalso` in the first case, that was simply to make the comment clearer.

Answer (score 4):

As an alternative to Vinoski's answer, you can also move the less specific pattern to the end, so lists are matched first:

```
guarded([X,Y]) when X>3,Y>3 ->{X+1,Y+1};
guarded([X,_|[T,_]]) when X rem 2==0, T rem 2 =/= 1-> [T,X];
guarded(T) when T>5 ; T<3 -> 3+T;
guarded(_)->"something else".
```

But in this specific case it won't work well, because something like `guarded([1,1])` will still not match the first two branches but will match the `T` one; this is because Erlang [allows comparing any two values](http://erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/expressions.html#term-comparisons) and simply considers lists greater than numbers.

Comment: So if there is no way to pattern match i am curious how is multiplicity tested in `Erlang` ? I mean how does a method like `is_list` (mentioned above) implemented?

Comment: This function would actually be easy to implement in Erlang: `is_list([]) -> true; is_list([_|_]) -> true; is_list(_) -> false.`. But this doesn't apply to e.g. `is_number`. In reality, both of them are implemented in C code, not in Erlang.

Answer (score 3):

> I mean how does a method like `is_list` (mentioned above) implemented?

Using erlang, you can implement `is_list()` like this:

```
-module(my).
-compile([export_all]).

islist([]) ->     % empty list
    true;
islist([_|_]) ->  % non-empty list
    true;
islist(_) ->      % anything else
    false.
```

When you call a function, erlang starts with the first function clause in the definition and tries to match the arguments specified in the function call to the parameters in the function definition.  If there's no match, erlang then tries the next function clause.  When a match is found, the corresponding function body executes.  If none of the function clauses match, then you get a `function_clause` error.

In the shell:

```
~/erlang_programs$ erl
Erlang/OTP 17 [erts-6.4] [source] [64-bit] [smp:4:4] [async-threads:10] [hipe] [kernel-poll:false]
Eshell V6.4  (abort with ^G)

1> c(my).
{ok,my}

2> my:islist(3).
false

3> my:islist({1, 2}).
false

4> my:islist([1, 2]).
true

5> my:islist([]).
true

6> my:islist("abc"). 
true
```

In line 6, you should be aware that `"abc"` is shorthand for the list of integers `[97, 98, 99]`.  In erlang, a double quoted string is shorthand for a list that contains the integer codepoints of the characters in the double quoted string.